# Compatibility of Javascript, HTML and CSS inside IFrame or nested IFrames

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, nested

I have an existing web site which is about to use a dynamic menu navigation system. To short, all the existing pages will be moved into iFrame's of the menu page.

JQuery, YUI Ajax, simple manual Javascript Ajax and variety of other Javascript libraries are used across all hurdreds pages.

My concern here is the compatibility issues that might come up when existing pages, with or without iFrame, are moved into menu iFrame.

For your information, my web site is developed by using Classic ASP.

Please refer me to a similar thread or just let me know your opinion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything inside an IFRAME is independent, it's almost as if it's a separate browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Iframes loaded into your page are completely sandboxed from other iframes, in fact, you cannot even call javascript between a container page and it's contained iframe, this is a security restriction within the browser.

People have devised elaborate workarounds to defeat this limitation of the browser ([etc](http://ternarylabs.com/2011/03/27/secure-cross-domain-iframe-communication/), [etc](http://milan.adamovsky.com/2012/03/reliable-cross-iframe-javascript.html), [etc](http://nicklothian.com/blog/2009/08/05/cross-domain-cross-window-javascript-communication/)).

That all said, you should be fine.